# Turning back rust on frame welds on a FJ Cruiser

Tags: toyota, rust, body-work, frame, fjcruiser

I recently purchased a 2007 FJ cruiser up here in the north where we use lots of salt. The only issue I noticed with this vehicle (and about half of the FJs I looked at) was rust developing along the welds in the frame.

What would be a good approach to getting control of this problem?  Make that a practical approach, I am not going to take the body off the frame and have it sand blasted and powder coated.

Would it be reasonable to have it undercoated or treated in some way?

I know that some undercoating is actually worse because it traps moisture and salt against the metal, is there a good option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some [POR15](http://www.por15.com/) which will stop the rust from spreading. It is really good on surface rust. I'm currently using it on my 1987 Toyota Land Cruiser and works well!

Answer (score 1):

You would be wise to get your vehicle on a hoist and clean up the rusted areas with a wire brush/grinder of various sizes. You can then apply primer or go straight to rubberized undercoat.

From there you would be ok to to get your vehicle undercoated from a shop. The key to this is cleanliness. Make sure your vehicles undercarriage is properly rinsed before the undercoat is sprayed.